# Git clone from unfuddle, how to not include the initial directory, which in this case is the name of the repository

Tags: git, git-clone, unfuddle

I have a git repository on unfuddle.com. I've been working locally on my windows machine using TortoiseGit. I'm ready to clone the repository onto a development server and I'm able to get all the files using

```
git clone git@subdomain.unfuddle.com:subdomain/nameofrepository.git
```

but this includes the `nameofrepository` directory as the initial directory and everything else is inside that. I'm new to git, how can I clone the repo without getting the `nameofrepository` directory? I would like to clone this into `public_html` of my development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the directory name or path you want to the `clone` command:

```
git clone repo_url /path/to/public_html/
```